# Comparing one line in a file to multiple lines in another file/FORTRAN

Tags: input, fortran, output

I am trying to compare two files, so make one line from one file be compared to alll the lines in the other file until it finds a match where the difference is less than 0.003.

This what I had thought of, but I still think it is just comparing line by line, instead of one line to all the other lines. Any suggestions would be great!

This is what I have so far:

```
program matchCoords
implicit none

real :: xcoord1, ycoord1,x1,y1,mag1,merr1,sharp1,chi1
real :: xcoord2, ycoord2,x2,y2,mag2,merr2,sharp2,chi2
real, parameter :: arcsec = 0.0003
character (len=50) :: inputfile1, inputfile2, outputfile
integer :: i, j


!Open input file as unit 15
write(*,*) 'Enter inputfile #1:'
read(*,*) inputfile1
write(*,*) 'Enter inputfile #2'
read(*,*) inputfile2
write(*,*) 'Enter output file name:'
read(*,*) outputfile
open(unit=15, file=inputfile1, status='old')
open(unit=16, file=inputfile2, status='old')
open(unit=17, file=outputfile, status='new')


do i=0,37200
read(16,*) xcoord2, ycoord2,x2,y2,mag2,merr2,sharp2,chi2
do j=0,37000
read(15,*) xcoord1(j), ycoord1(j),x1,y1,mag1,merr1,sharp1,chi1

if(ABS(xcoord1(j)-xcoord2).le.arcsec.and.ABS(ycoord1(i)-ycoor&
&d2).le.arcsec) then

write(17,*) xcoord1(j),ycoord1(j),x1,y1,mag1,merr1,&
&sharp1,chi1,xcoord2,ycoord2,x2,y2,&
&mag2,merr2,sharp2,chi2
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks that it is comparing every line to every other line.  If would be good to see the completion of the loops and IF statement.  Your code would be easier to read with indentation for the logic.

Comment: File IO is terribly slow, you are far more likely to get a faster run time by reading the data into the arrays, then cycling through those arrays, rather than repeatedly reading the files directly.